# why UIView variables could not create retain cycle problem?

Tags: uiview, swift4.2, retain-cycle

When I searched code of UIView , I could not understand  that why superview and subviews properities does not create retain cycle?

```
extension UIView {

open var superview: UIView? { get }

open var subviews: [UIView] { get }

open var window: UIWindow? { get }
```

Answer (score 0):

A computed property is just a pair of a getter and a setter (or, in this case, it's a read-only property which is only a getter). The declaration doesn't tell you how any underlying data that the property uses might be stored or memory-managed.

Answer (score 0):

> I could not understand that why superview and subviews properities does not create retain cycle?

It's because the view hierarchy is a directed graph with respect to retains. Views retain their subviews, but subviews don't retain their superviews.